# How to achieve this filtering in R programming language?

Tags: r, data-science

I have the following 4 columns in a data frame in R:

```
ID    A     B     C    Revenue
1     0     1     0    2.33
1     1     1     0    3.1 
2     1     0     1    4   
2     0     0     1    5.22
2     1     1     0    6.45
3     0     0     0    3   
3     0     0     0    2   
4     1     1     1    7.22
4     0     0     0    1.22
4     1     1     0    4.55
4     0     1     1    1
```

`A`, `B`, and `C` are categorical values.
I want to create 3  data frames with 3 columns with columns names: `ID`, `0`, `1`. In column `0` I want avg. of `Revenue` for `A = 0` rows and in column `1` average of `Revenue` for `A = 1` for each distinct `ID`. Likewise for `B` and `C` in two other data frames.
I am unable to figure out how to do it with `dplyr` or any package for that matter.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also write a custom function that does what you want using `tidy_eval`.
The syntax takes a bit of getting used to, but it's very useful once you get the hang of it.

```
require(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4),
             A = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0),
             B = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1), C = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1),
             Revenue = c(2.33,3.1,4,5.22,6.45,3,2,7.22,1.22,4.55,1))

create_df_mean <- function(df, mean_var, pos_spread, ...){
  group_var <- enquos(...) # get the grouping columns
  spread_var <- group_var[[pos_spread]] # get the column used as key to spread df
  mean_var <- enquo(mean_var) # get the column used to calculate mean
  df <- df %>%
  group_by(!!!group_var) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(!!mean_var)) %>% 
  spread(!!spread_var, mean)
  return(df)
}
# arguments are:
# 1. data frame
# 2. column for calc. mean
# 3. the position of the spread key in grouping columns
# 4. grouping columns
create_df_mean(df, Revenue, 2, ID, A)
```

You can customise this function even further following these tutorials: [1](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) and [2](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: you're passing the grouping columns as `...` arguments to the `create_df_mean` function. with `pos_spread` you tell the function which of the grouping columns you want to use as the key in `spread` function (in the example above, I wanted to use `A`, which is the second grouping column, hence `pos_spread=2`). tbh, you can also code it up in such way that you pass the key column explicitly (similarly to `mean_var`), but I didn't want to be repetitive + less typing if you have long column names.

Comment: So my A column number is 16 and when i do give that it says subscript out of bounds error

Comment: And '...' grouping columns in my case would be ID right

Comment: `pos_spread` is the position of the column (the one you want to spread) among the grouping columns, not its number in the df (in my example, coincidentally, they're the same). you can see how I've used it in `create_df_mean(df, Revenue, 2, ID, A)`. `Revenue` is the column for which I calculate the mean, grouping columns are `ID` and `A` and then I want to spread the data over column `A` which is at position 2 in the grouping columns. If I listed the grouping columns as `A` and `ID`, then I'd have to change `pos_spread` to 1 and the example would be `create_df_mean(df, Revenue, 1, A, ID)`

Comment: How do i rename to I'd , zero,one

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What would you like to rename to ID, zero, one? At which point?

Comment: As in ' 0' and '1' i want to give names 'zero and one'respectively..maybe after spread function?

Comment: oh yeah, you can use the `rename` function from `tidyverse` and add the following after `spread`: `rename(zero = \`0\`, one = \`1\`)`

Comment: Is this the correct syntax or is it rename all? Coz it's showing me error in rename(.data,.dots=copat_as_lazy_dots(..)) .data missing with no default  " error

Comment: ```create_df_mean <- function(df, mean_var, pos_spread, ...){
    group_var <- enquos(...) # get the grouping columns
    spread_var <- group_var[[pos_spread]] # get the column used as key to spread df
    mean_var <- enquo(mean_var) # get the column used to calculate mean
    df <- df %>%
        group_by(!!!group_var) %>% 
        summarise(mean = mean(!!mean_var)) %>% 
        spread(!!spread_var, mean) %>% 
        rename(zero = `0`, one = `1`)
    return(df)
}```
This works for me - just be careful, b/c `0` and `1` are surrounded by backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Oh oops I put single quotes .Also o have a disturbing doubt the other answer to this question provided down calculates mean of 0  for 1 and vice Versa. What do you think is the error

Comment: The answer below gives the same results as my answer and I think both codes are correct.

Comment: Nope if you closely see his answer calculate mean of 0 variable and is listed on 1 column and mean of 1 variable in 0 column

Comment: For which variable? I think you're mistaken, as I get the same results for all 3 variables.

Comment: After ID there is two columns 0 and 1. The mean of 1 is displayed under 0 and vice versa

Comment: it is not and you can see that for ID = 1. Column A has 0 for revenue of 2.33 and 1 for revenue of 3.1 and those exact numbers appear under correct column names.

Comment: In dplyr select should the order of giving variables be same as  that in dataframe?

Comment: Thanks , but unfortunately in the solution code given by the other person ,only when i order dplyr  select  in the same order as that of dataframe it works correctly otherwise mean of 0 and 1 get swapped.Could there be any logical reason to this ?

Comment: I'm really not sure. the code works with the minimal example given here. maybe ask @Ronak Shah

Comment: My comments are disabled for that unfortunately.once it's active will do so

Comment: If you can help  could you pls upvote this question of mine

Comment: Hi the last line you have written where we pass the parameters and and give column name in df as last parameter and we fet a df, can that be used in lapply or for loop so that say i want to get for 10 columns instead of repeatatively writing that line

Answer (score 2):

One way using `dplyr`  and `tidyr` could be to `gather` data to long format, get `mean` value for each `ID`, `value` and `key` and `spread` it to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID, -Revenue) %>%
  group_by(ID, value, key) %>%
  summarise(mean_rev = mean(Revenue)) %>%
  spread(value, mean_rev, fill = 0)


#     ID key     `0`   `1`
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 A      2.33  3.1 
# 2     1 B      0     2.72
# 3     1 C      2.72  0   
# 4     2 A      5.22  5.22
# 5     2 B      4.61  6.45
# 6     2 C      6.45  4.61
# 7     3 A      2.5   0   
# 8     3 B      2.5   0   
# 9     3 C      2.5   0   
#10     4 A      1.11  5.88
#11     4 B      1.22  4.26
#12     4 C      2.88  4.11
```

If you need them in separate dataframes with only three columns we can use `group_split`

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID, -Revenue) %>%
  group_by(ID, value, key) %>%
  summarise(mean_rev = mean(Revenue)) %>%
  spread(value, mean_rev, fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_split(key, keep = FALSE)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ID   `0`   `1`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2.33  3.1 
#2     2  5.22  5.22
#3     3  2.5   0   
#4     4  1.11  5.88

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ID   `0`   `1`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  0     2.72
#2     2  4.61  6.45
#3     3  2.5   0   
#4     4  1.22  4.26

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ID   `0`   `1`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2.72  0   
#2     2  6.45  4.61
#3     3  2.5   0   
#4     4  2.88  4.11
```

To get the output into separate dataframe, we can do

```
df1 <- df %>% 
         dplyr::select(ID, A, B, C, Revenue) %>% 
         gather(key, value, -ID, -Revenue) %>% 
         group_by(ID, value, key) %>%
         summarise(mean_rev = mean(Revenue)) %>%
         spread(value, mean_rev, fill = 0) %>%
         ungroup() %>%
         group_split(key, keep = FALSE)

names(df1) <- LETTERS[seq_along(df1)]
list2env(df1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi i have a big doubt, in select i have taken ( ID,A,B,C,D, Revenue) and did the same code as above , but shockingly i am getting mean of 0 for 0 and 1 for 1 only for  B and D whereas for A and C columns it shows reverse meaning mean of 0 for 1 and vice versa what could be the issue you think ?? Something to do with group_by and spread?

Comment: I kind of know what the problem is , say for column A if key starts with 0 it's mapping correctly but for B if it starts with 1 it's mapping in 0 column.Any solution to this ?